# Remove additional space while entering data to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an android application that sends some array of strings to php. php takes that array and inserts that data value individually into database. now when the data is inserted, each row data get an additional white space along with it. 
how to eliminate it. i tried REPLACE with the string but when tried REPLACE, am unable to insert anything.
a white space is added when second row is entered.

here is the PHP code for entering data.

```
<?php
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['docname']) && isset($_POST['prods'])) {

    $docname = $_POST['docname'];
    $prods = $_POST['prods'];

    $e = trim($prods, '[]');
    $pr = preg_split("/[,]/", $e);

    $img = "image/";

    //$docs=array_unique($pr);

    $count = count($pr);

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    // selecting database
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    foreach ($pr as $val) {

        $img = $img . $val . ".jpg";

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysqli_query($con, 
            "INSERT INTO product_entered(id, doc_name, product_name, image_path, count) 
            VALUES('$id','$docname','$val','$img','$count')"
        );
    }

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {

        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else {

        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 
else {

    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

when i display it using JSON, it looks like this..

```
 {
        "id": "15",
        "doc_name": "Dr. XYZ",
        "product_name": " PROTONIL-D",
        "image_path": "image/image/ PROTONIL-D.jpg",
        "count": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "doc_name": "Dr. XYZ",
        "product_name": " PROATH_PLUS",
        "image_path": "image/image/ PROATH_PLUS.jpg",
        "count": "7"
    },
```

a white space is inserted every time a row is inserted
i don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($prods)` and paste the result in the question?

Comment: how to do it coz i have multiple check boxes in android application, when i select some  of them and send it to php code, this is executed in background.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do a `trim ()` in the loop?

```
foreach ($pr as $val) {
    $val = trim($val);

    $img = $img . $val . ".jpg";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, 
        "INSERT INTO product_entered(id, doc_name, product_name, image_path, count) 
        VALUES('$id','$docname','$val','$img','$count')"
    );
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried TRIM and also REPLACE . but didn't worked

Comment: Have not been hidden value as ^M that appear if you are not in a utf8 encoding without bom and with MS Windows ? Did you also try to change IDE?

Comment: sorry .. i am unable to understand what you are trying to tell. r u telling me to use IDE like eclipse or netbeans or dreamviewer..?

Comment: Some IDE can sometimes have problems encoding or insert spéiciaux characters, without being seen. That is why it is sometimes wise to open and save the file with another editor.

Comment: so MS Windows, try Vim just for characters